# What is the problem with my Fetch request from Nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, token

Everytime i make a fetch request i get an error:

```
server running on 8000 port
{ type: 'https://httpstatus.es/401',
  status: 401,
  title: 'Unauthorized',
  detail: 'Access token invalid or expired' }
```

I keep getting a new token and it still shows that error
this is my method, im not sure what im doing wrong

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
const token = {SOME LONG ASS TOKEN HERE};

fetch('https://api.petfinder.com/v2/animals?sort=random', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `token ${token}`
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
})
```

it works on postman but not in my backend
im super confused lol

Comment: Is your JWT token valid?

Comment: i am able to make the fetch request on postman 
so im guessing it is, but once i try on Express it just doesnt go thru

Comment: Do i have to tell it the type of token it is?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work 
i changed token to Bearer on my authorization 
so:

```
headers: {
   Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
}
```